# How to get string resources from specific resource file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, localization

In some cases in our project ***we have to ignore current culture*** of application
and get resources in English.

Basically, we do it like for all languages

```
<label>@ModelEntities.Properties.Resource.Gender</label>
```

How is it possible to get in English only?

I assume we have somehow created some reference to `Resource.resx` ?

I have used

```
 ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Resource.Strings",
                     Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ModelEntities.Properties.Resource))); 
  var s = rm.GetString("Age");
```

But it seems like not working.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the working solution.

First of all our resource files are ending like

> Resource.resx

and not like `Resources.resx`

And in second we have resources in a separate assembly: **ModelEntities**

So the working code is following

```
var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(typeof(ModelEntities.Properties.Resource)); 
var genderString = resourceManager.GetString("Gender", ci);
```

Comment: thanks is works,, for the "ci" definition got it from the previous answer

Answer (score 7):

You can use the resource manager class [click here for more info about the class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"); 
ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager("YourResource", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); 
string bodyResource = resourceManager.GetString("yourText", ci);
```

Comment: Why do you frame `C#` code into a snippet like this?

Comment: my guess is he didn't realize what code snippets were for, as he's a rather new user. I have edited the answer and replaced it with a simple code block

Comment: Indeed I am a new user. Used the Tidy functionality.Thanks Anthony Shaw

Answer (score 5):

A simple way:

```
YorResourceName.ResourceManager.GetString("ResourceKeyName", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Folder structure:

MyApplicationSolution 
         /Resources
            /Resource.resx

```
public static string GetLocalisedRes(string resourceName = "", string resourceNameKey = "")
    {
        string translate = string.Empty;
        string baseName = "YourNameSpace.Resources." + resourceName + "";

        try
        {
            Type resType = Type.GetType(baseName);
            ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(baseName, resType.Assembly);
            translate = rm.GetString(resourceNameKey);
        }
        catch {
            translate = string.Empty;
        }
        return translate;
    }
```

Usage

```
    var age = GetLocalisedRes("Resource", "Age");
```

This working for me